# Excel - Updating Month For 2 Fixed Days Each Month

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to fix 2 days and update the month for every new month. E.g.

```
1/10/15
1/22/15
2/10/15
2/22/15
3/10/15
3/22/15
```

and on and on. I want to do this in one cell in Excel 2013. So after a certain date passes, it automatically triggers the next coming date.

Comment: Your wording is a little confusing. I *think* you are trying to create a row of consecutive dates containing only the 10th and 22nd of each month (but not any intermediate days). Is this correct?

Comment: Please let me know if I am clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  It evaluates the current date and will return the next 10th or 22nd of the month.

```
=IF(DAY(TODAY())<=10,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),10),IF(DAY(TODAY())<=22,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),22),DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,10)))
```